# Tesseract OSD script detection outputs

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract on a multi-lingual project, so I'm trying to use the OSD feature to extract the script type, to then hand that as an input for the `lang` for Tesseract's OCR text detection. I ran a Chinese language document through the OSD, and it returned "Han" as the script, but that is not a valid input for `lang`, it has to be one of HanS, HanS_Vert, HanT, or HanT_Vert. This is fine, but I can't find a list of possible OSD output scripts so I can build an appropriate dictionary to translate that output to OCR input. Does anyone know where that list might exist? There's the Languages and Scripts page [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html), but that's only the valid OCR inputs -- notably "Han" does not appear by itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a Lang and a Script detection. Tesseract does not do language detection (correct language code is a must parameter for good OCR results).

Tesseract script detection is [very limited](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/dc228edc566a3788f26048f7f8300f6517229a3a/src/ccmain/osdetect.cpp#L51-L61) and it has not improved for the year 2009.

Comment: I've had it pick up Cyrillic, Arabic, and Hebrew, which aren't in that list. So I am a little curious where those would live. I'm also just looking for the script; the language detection is separate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the documentation you posted looks incomplete. Based on my test Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese are both recognized with script Han (I din't try the vertical ones). I don't honestly know why since they have a different set of characters, maybe they just combined both in a single model. Except for chinese, which I force to be "Han" since most of the text out there is in simplified chinese, the rest of the scripts seems to be OK.
However I'd like to suggest a different approach. After detecting the script with `image_to_osd` you can use `image_to_string` to extract the text and then use [polyglot](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot) to detect the exact language. After that I use [easyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) for an accurate detection.